# stop tracking deleted files present in working directory in git

Tags: git

I have some deleted files in working directory, These are some library files that are missing. I want git to ignore them. Adding it to .gitignore would not help as they are already being tracked by git

Comment: You "have" some "deleted" files? Now what? Do you have them or did you delete them?

Comment: I don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

For a single file, you can use the following to untract

```
git rm myfile
```

In the newer versions of git, those files are automatically untracked with

```
git add --update
```

Comment: using git rm adds the deleted file from working directory to staging area, git add --update does not have any effect

Comment: @gopal `git rm` adds the *removal* of the file to the staging area.